# Generating data summaries, row counts for multiple columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, visualization, summary

I have a registration system. So basically, I have fields like `age`, `gender`, etc.

This is a simplified schema of my MySQL Database:

```
---------------------------------------
| id | name | age | gender | category |
---------------------------------------
```

Basically I want to generate overall reports like the total number of registrants in a category, total number of males, total number of females, etc.

I have a basic knowledge of `SQL`. I know that I can use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` to see "summaries" for a single column. So basically, I'd have to do multiple queries to get "summaries" for all columns. Can I do this in one query instead?

I also am going to provide detailed summaries. By this I mean, I'd have to tally how many males are in a `category`, how many minors are in a category, etc. It's sort of like a `category X age`, `category X gender` summary. Again, I know how to do this using multiple queries but I would like some opinion on a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can accomplish wat you're looking for using `WITH ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT id, name, age, gender, category, count(*) cnt
from my_table
GROUP BY id. name, age, gender, category
WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: Worked like magic! I noticed that this gives me a new row for every value of age (which is the expected behavior). If I want to group ages into minors and adults how will I do this??

Comment: Add the field to the field list and group by list that reads something like this: `IF(age < 18, 'minor', 'adult')`